# Not sure conceptwise where I am wrong in optional chaining in swift..Can anyone please explain why the output is that?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-chaining

```
class ElectionPoll {
    var candidate: Pollbooth?
}
class Pollbooth {
    var name = "MP"
}
let cand = ElectionPoll()

if let candname = cand.candidate?.name {
    print("Candidate name is \(candname)")
} else {
    print("Candidate name cannot be retreived")
}
```

In the above code I thought the output would be Candidate name is MP but the output is Candidate name cannot be retreived. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Because ```cand.candidate``` has a ```nil``` value. If u use ```var cand = ElectionPoll()``` ```cand.candidate = Pollbooth()``` then u will get ```MP```

Comment: why the cand.candidate has a nil value ? I know its optional and may have a nil value but in the Pollbooth class it the value is assigned there

Comment: @Vyankatesh you just declare a variable `var candidate: Pollbooth?` not set any value. That's why `card.candiate` is nil.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks @Faysal. So by doing this -> cand.candidate = Pollbooth() we are creating object of it right? And then it wont be nil? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: By doing this -> cand.candidate = Pollbooth() you just assigned a new Pollbooth object to cand.candidate variable. And it contains some value that is not nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
var candidate: Pollbooth?
```

This creates a candidate variable with type of `Pollbooth`.

```
let cand = ElectionPoll()
```

In this line just creates `ElectionPoll` object. When you try to execute this `cand.candidate?.name` the `cand.candidate` variable is nil because you cannot set any value.

If you try to get the value directly then you can try this way

```
let cand = ElectionPoll()
cand.candidate = Pollbooth()
```

Or

```
class ElectionPoll {
    var candidate = Pollbooth()
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has little to do with optional chaining, you just didn't set any value to `candidate`.

What you do is creating an `ElectionPoll` variable:

```swift
let cand = ElectionPoll()
```

The `candidate` property of `ElectionPoll` is `Optional` and thus implicitly has a `nil` default value. Classes in Swift only have inherited and an empty initializers. So unless you add an `init(candidate: Pollbooth?)`, the only way to provide `candidate` with a value is through the property:

```swift
cand.candidate = Pollbooth()
```

And after that `candidate` finally has its non-`nil` value.